# Error deleting older kernel package

Tags: debian, kernel

Today I tried to remove the old kernel in Debian Stretch with

```
sudo aptitude purge linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

While the procedure went smoothly in most of the servers, and has been going smoothly over several years, this time I got the following error in 2 of my servers:

```
Failed to substitute package name in title: 10 at /usr/bin/linux-check-removal line 102, < STDIN> line 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
E: Sub-process  /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Using

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Also returns a similar message.

Trying to repeat uninstall/purge commands of this package always give this error.

How would I be able to delete it?

Comment: Which kernel were the servers *running* when `linux-check-removal` failed?

Comment: @StephenKitt Most of them 4.9.0-3...however the script is supposed to ask yes/no in that case, and not fail. From around 80 servers, two failed; one had dkms+sysdig, the other was a plain install.

Comment: Yes, the failure at line 102 means it somehow failed to ask the question. I was just curious whether you’d rebooted since installing 4.9.0-4; I wouldn’t have tried removing the kernel before doing that ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Have done it since Squeeze at least. I only reboot as a last resource, or with a serious security hole. I do not run alsa in VMs. ;-P

Comment: As do I, at least for non-Internet-facing systems — but I keep the running kernel installed, that’s all. You’ve found a weird bug...

Comment: I will invest some time going deeper *if* it happens again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigating a workaround, I noticed that `/usr/bin/linux-check-removal` is a Perl script; according to `man`:

> linux-check-removal - check whether removal of a kernel is safe
>
> SYNOPSIS.
>          linux-check-removal VERSION
>
> DESCRIPTION.
>          linux-check-removal  is intended to be called from the prerm maintainer
>          scripts of Linux kernel packages.

At the end of the day, I just modified the script to return 0 (success), uninstalled the package, with

```
sudo aptitude purge linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

and restored the script at the end of the operation.

My temporary modification, applied at the end of the script, was:

```
# replace check() call with exit with success code
# check(@ARGV);
exit 0;
```